# Make JMS Serializer not populate null values instead of defaults

Tags: php, symfony4, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

JMS Serializer 1.* on deserialization populates only those fields that are provided in the input. For instance, we have code like:

```
$criteria = $this->serializer->deserialize($request->getContent(), SearchCriteria::class, 'json');
```

And when there is no field `limit` provided in request it takes default value, defined in class property, i.e.

```
class SearchCriteria {
    // ...
    private $limit = 10;
    // ...
}
```

This behavior has changed after migrating to JMS Serializer 2.0 - now it overrides `limit` field with null, which breaks our logic. Is there a way to configure old behavior? We use Symfony 4 with jms/serializer-bundle@3.0.0.

Here is `jms_serializer.yaml`:

```
jms_serializer:
    default_context:
        serialization:
            serialize_null: false
        deserialization:
            serialize_null: false
```

Answer (score 2):

So the best workaround I found so far is using PostDeserialize annotation (https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#postdeserialize) and manually setting defaults, like:

```
/**
 * @JMS\PostDeserialize()
 */
public function postDeserialize()
{
    $this->limit = $this->limit ?? 10;
}
```

It looks ugly yet works.

Comment: This is riddiculous (not your solution, but that there is no other way).
What are @Type-annotations for if null values just get written into attirbutes via reflection anyway?